# iOS app breaks after launching since adding Appodeal framework

Tags: ios, ads

My app worked without any problem, but after adding Appodeal framework to my project, app began to break after launching. I have the latest Appodeal SDK and Xcode 7.2.1

```
2016-02-06 20:09:31.737 AD[557:189747] SourceKit Logger: log level set to none
2016-02-06 20:09:31.935 AD[557:189747] PodAppodeal_SKMRAIDInterstitial MRAIDViewDelegate mraidViewAdReady:
2016-02-06 20:09:32.626 AD[557:189747] SourceKit Logger: log level set to none
2016-02-06 20:09:32.677 AD[557:189747] PodAppodeal_SKMRAIDInterstitial MRAIDViewDelegate mraidViewAdReady:
2016-02-06 20:09:33.052 AD[557:189747] SourceKit Logger: log level set to none
2016-02-06 20:09:33.104 AD[557:189747] PodAppodeal_SKMRAIDInterstitial MRAIDViewDelegate mraidViewAdReady:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - please check your podfile. It must be look like this:

```
platform :ios, '7.1'

source 'https://github.com/appodeal/CocoaPods.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'iosdemo' do

    pod 'Appodeal', '~> 0.8.1' # for XCODE 7

#   pod 'Appodeal', '0.4.8' # for XCODE 6.4

    pod 'MWFeedParser', '~> 1.0'

end
```

If you have problems with versions of pods please run

```
rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"
rm -rf "`pwd`/Pods/"
pod update
```

Also please check your build settings:

```
iOS SDK 0.7.0+
Deployment target: iOS 7.1 and up
```

I would like to see a full log (Stack trace). It really can help to see what going on there.

You can discuss with us in anytime via chat at appodeal site.  We will help you rummage through this issue.

UPD: 
Is it okay now? If it's not - please send me a full log (Stack trace). I will assist you.

Comment: UPD: 
Is it okay now? If it's not - please send me a full log (Stack trace). I will assist you.